# Python Dataframe: Assign values to a column based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a df with `name` and `status` with present and absent as values.

```
            name     status
    0      anthony   present
    1      anthony   absent
    2      mason     present
    3      donny     present
    4      donny     absent
    5      donny     absent
    6      paul      present
    7      paul      present
```

I'm trying to put status - `True or False` for each name.

If one of the `name` has `absent` their status will be False

Expected Output:

```
            name     output
    0      anthony   False
    1      mason     True
    2      donny     False
    3      paul      True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare `status` to `'present'` then get the mininum by `name`:

```
# or `all()` instead of `min()`
df['status'].eq('present').groupby(df['name']).min()
```

Output:

```
name
anthony    False
donny      False
mason       True
paul        True
Name: status, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to groupby name and find if a name has present as the only status.

```
df.groupby('name')['status'].apply(lambda x: (x=='present').all())



    name
    anthony    False
    donny      False
    mason       True
    paul        True
```